# How to enable radiobutton1 and textbox4 if values are present in textbox1, textbox2, textbox3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a formview in asp page which contains 4 textboxes and a radio button. On clicking the edit button it should display radiobutton1 and textbox4 if values are present in textbox1, textbox2, textbox3(i.e if any one of the textboxes(1,2,3) is empty it should not display textbox1 and radiobutton)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Check my answer. If you don't want to use jQuery, DnshPly9's answer is also very good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$("#idOfEditButton").live('click', function(){

    if(!$('#idOfTxt1').val() || !$('#idOfTxt2').val() || !$('#idOfTxt3').val()){
        $('#idOfRadio').hide();
        $('#idOfTxt4').hide();   
    }
    else{
        $('#idOfRadio').show();
        $('#idOfTxt4').show();  
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

You can also use classes, then you add `$('.classNameOfAllTxt')` in the if statement (only once).
And `$('.classfTxt4AndRadio').show(); // or hide`.

Answer (score 0):

In the formview editing event, Find the controls and check if the textbox contains text like

TextBox textbox1 = formView.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

Similarly find TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4 and Radiobutton1

then compare

```
if(textbox1.Text != string.Empty && textBox2.Text != string.Empty && textBox3.Text != string.Empty)
{
    textbox4.Visible = true;
    Radiobutton1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    // set visibility to false
}
```

Do this like in the event below for

```
    protected void FormView1_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FormView1.CurrentMode == System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewMode.Edit)
        {
            **// Find Controls and Check ConditionHere**
        }
    }
```

Try it. Hope it helps.

For Javascript try something like :

```
 function Check() {
        var b = document.getElementById("<%= FormView1.FindControl("textBox1").ClientID%>");
        var a = document.getElementById("<%= FormView1.FindControl("textBox2").ClientID%>");

        if(a.innerText === "" && b.innerText == "")
        {
              // find the control like above and set visibility to false
              var textbox4 = ....;
              textbox4.visibility = "block"; // attribute for visibility is not verified by me, check to see the correct one if you have problem hidding or showing.
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry you are right, but you can try it in ModeChanged event??? Something like FormView1.CurrentMode == System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewMode.Edit then do it...... Javascript! Yes it's possible but i have to try it first

Comment: Sorry but I tested my javascript code but not server side code, try using FormViewDiagnostic PreRender Event like the link shows  http://forums.asp.net/post/2560651.aspx